# WebRTC Video Streaming fails through Airtel Fiber, works fine with 4G and other ISP like ACT, TTN

Tags: video, webrtc, streaming, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I have setup a webRTC peer on a remote machine using the RTCbot python project. My goal is to access the webcam and microphone remotely. I setup a turn server on an AWS instance and I'm able to watch the video feed and hear the audio on a remote browser on my 4G ISP in India (Jio). But I am not able to view the video via my broadband ISP - Airtel. I had my friends check the link on other ISPs like ACT and TTN and they seem to be fine. Is there anything I have to configure on my router to get this working? Or should I approach the ISP?